# Einstein Analytics

Tags: managed-package, deployment, einstein-analytics, package, einstein

I'm working on managed package where it is deployed to many users. We are now adding new Einstein Analytics Templates and dashboard in the managed packages. If end user don't have analytics enabled or don't have required licenses does my package fails to deploy  the latest version to the users ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had registered case at Salesforce. So the answer is that it would give an error if the end user don't have Einstein Licenses. What Salesforce recommends is that develop it on extension packages when packaging Einstein Analytics templates. Different Components have different pricing. We need to build Einstein Apps as an Extension package to their base app so we don't run into this issue.

Hope this helps if anyone ran into the same problem.